# ActiveMQ integration with Oracle Service bus(OSB) 12c

Tags: activemq-classic, weblogic12c, osb

we are trying to do the assessment around ActiveMQ to use in OSB 12c as JMS based integration. I did follow few blogs like https://bizzperform.com/blog/?p=686 but this is not helping and generating error like below.

did anyone came across this scenario and did implemented same .. kinldy advise.

```
<Failed to check whether connection factory LocalConnectionFactory supports XA. Will assume it does not: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
```

Answer (score 0):

Active MQ client jar is missing from domain class path, you need to download it and add to PRE_CLASSPATH

Comment: Hello, thanks for your quick response. I have added below JAR in my domain path and can see its even loading while I restart domain - set PRE_CLASSPATH=%DOMAIN_HOME%\lib\activemq-client-5.16.3.jar;%PRE_CLASSPATH%

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I finally got it working.

two  quick changes and that worked

1. added the jar file in setDomainEnv.cmd like this
   set PRE_CLASSPATH=%DOMAIN_HOME%\lib\activemq-all-5.16.3.jar;%PRE_CLASSPATH%
   or you can put the complete URL of domain home.
2. while configuring the JMS on OSB, its always tricky to set the JNDI and I had to use both like below
   jms://localhost:7001//

this helped and established a connection.